# Установка зависимостей в setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

Делаю package из [репозитория](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/email-client).

У меня есть [гит-репа](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/table-tests), которую я хочу подтянуть как зависимость. В ней прописаны в `requirements`:

```
table-tests==0.4.1
requests==2.22.0
pytest==5.0.1
python-dotenv==0.10.3
```

Также, в `setup.py`, я делаю:

```
import setuptools


def parse_requirements(filename):
    """ load requirements from a pip requirements file """
    lineiter = (line.strip() for line in open(filename))
    return [line for line in lineiter if line and not line.startswith("#")]


with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

install_reqs = parse_requirements('./requirements')
print(install_reqs)

setuptools.setup(
    name="email-clients",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Egor Urvanov",
    author_email="hedgehogues@bk.ru",
    description="Email clients for grader and other services of fless.pro",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/Hedgehogues/email-clients",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7+",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'git+https://github.com/hedgehogues/table-tests@0.4.1#egg=table-tests-0.4.1'
    ],
    install_requires=install_reqs,
)
```

Здесь важно: `dependency_links`. После того, как я запускаю установку, я получаю ошибку:

> Installed
>
> /home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader-email-client/lib/python3.7/site-packages/email_clients-1.0.0-py3.7.egg
>
> Processing dependencies for email-clients==1.0.0 Searching for
>
> table-tests==0.4.1 Doing git clone from
>
> https://github.com/hedgehogues/table-tests to
>
> /tmp/easy_install-1k_z5dsc/table-tests@0.4.1 Checking out 0.4.1 Best
>
> match: table-tests 0.4.1 Processing table-tests@0.4.1 Writing
>
> /tmp/easy_install-1k_z5dsc/table-tests@0.4.1/setup.cfg Running
>
> setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir
>
> /tmp/easy_install-1k_z5dsc/table-tests@0.4.1/egg-dist-tmp-geyxx6dh
>
> zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents... Removing
>
> /home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader-email-client/lib/python3.7/site-packages/table_test-0.4.1-py3.7.egg
>
> Moving table_test-0.4.1-py3.7.egg to
>
> /home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader-email-client/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>
> table-test 0.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Installed
>
> /home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader-email-client/lib/python3.7/site-packages/table_test-0.4.1-py3.7.egg
>
> **error: The 'table-tests==0.4.1' distribution was not found and is required by email-clients**

При этом, установка проходит успешно. Но, от ошибки хочется избавится. Также мотивация в пользу избавления от ошибки -- это потребность запуска в docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одним из решений является добавление пакета в `pypi.org`. Это довольно просто. Для этого, Вам достаточно прочитать [эту статью](https://djangofan.ru/publikaciya-paketa-na-pypi). Как всегда, есть нюансы. Например, во многих статьях пишут устаревший репозиторий. Если Ваш репозиторий будет устаревшим, `setuputils` ругнётся и Вы узнаете об этом. Ваш .pypirc файл должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
[distutils]
index-servers=pypi

[pypi]
repository=https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ 
username=my-username
password=my-password
```

После того, как будет проделано такое упражнение, Вы сможете отказаться от `dependency_links` и пользоваться только чистым `requirements`. Это избавляет Вас от кучи боли.

Comment: не пробовали poetry для публикации проекта? им довольно просто пользоваться и за считанные минуты можно опубликовать пакет на pypi

Comment: @Serhii В чём отличиет от `twine`? Там тоже ничего сложного

Comment: я давно twine использовал, в последнее время попробовал poetry и его юзаю. может вам понравится, попробуйте, если хотите =)

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Поставлю себе на заметку.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то у тебя проблема в том, что [пакет в репе называется `table-test`](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/table-tests/blob/26f019be0dd4050e440aaed7f1e03b1046c30f85/setup.py#L16):

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="table-test",
    ...
)
```

а в зависимостях несуществующий пакет `table-tests`. `dependency_links` тут ни при чем. Просто исправь имя либо пакета, либо зависимости и приведи их к общему знаменателю.

Кстати, насчет советов в комментах: тут ни `poetry` не поможет - там тоже надо прописывать пару "имя пакета/ссылка на проект", а-ля

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
table-test = { git = "https://github.com/hedgehogues/table-tests.git", tag = "0.4.1" }
```

ни публикация проекта на PyPI, индексироваться он тоже будет по имени пакета в метадате, загрузится по ссылке https://pypi.org/project/table-test и устанавливаться будет через

```
pip install table-test
```

а не `table-tests`.

Хотя в целом совет перехода на `poetry` дельный, имхо она гораздо удобнее для простых юзкейсов, да и декларативный подход лучше написания скрипта.